# How to embed maps created using Googleengine into iframe object for a better viewing on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova-3, google-maps-engine, google-maps-engine-lite

I have created a custom map using mapsengine.google.com and then i export using the embed in my website option which generate an iframe object for me. I then added the iframe object to my HTML5 file which i am using to design a mobile app.

However when i try to view it from my mobile app it display an annoying panel which has info about the routes. All i want is to just show the map and the routes not the info panel.

Is there a better way to show this on my mobile app?

```
<iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=z0-DS05yFIOY.kk3gqtVGUw90" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: Make a button, launch the App in native Map App.

Comment: Hi @Raptor Can you explain little more in detail or maybe a tutorial link if you have any ? thanks

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147131/opening-native-map-app-from-javascript-without-relying-on-longitude-and-lattitud