# Open Mobile Device's Maps When user Click Button.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing mobile application using phonegap. In my application, I have one button, which is "view location". When the user click on that button, device maps should be open and after the maps opened, and user click back, it should back to my application. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Android intents list](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html) it should be possible using the `q` parameter within the `geo:` URI space.

Try this for Android:

```
<a href="geo:0,0?q=Bacau">Test</a>
```

or

```
<a href="geo:38.897096,-77.036545">open map</a>
```

iOS:

```
<a href="maps:q=someaddress" target="_blank" />
```

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147131/opening-native-map-app-from-javascript-without-relying-on-longitude-and-lattitud) - Credit to Dpa99c, [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745096/android-phonegap-how-to-open-native-google-maps-application) - Credit to Simon MacDonald

At this time all of this functionality is not unified under a single API. You will have to deal with each platform separately.